# From Python execute shell command and incorporate environment changes (without subprocess)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment

I'm exploring using iPython as shell replacement for a workflow that requires good logging and reproducibility of actions.

I have a few non-python binary programs and bash shell commands to run during my common workflow that manipulate the environment variables affecting subsequent work.  i.e.  when run from bash, the environment changes.

How can I incorporate these cases into the Python / iPython interactive shell and modify the environment going forward in the session?

Let's focus on the most critical case.
From bash, I woud do:

```
> sysmanager initialize foo
```

where `sysmanager` is a function:

```
> type sysmanager
sysmanager is a function
sysmanager () 
{ 
  eval `/usr/bin/sysmanagercmd bash $*`
}
```

I don't control the binary `sysmanagercmd` and it generally makes non-trivial manipulations of the environment variables. Use of the `eval` built-in means these manipulations affect the shell process going forward -- that's critical to the design.

How can I call this command from Python / iPython with the same affect?  Does python have something equivalent to bash's `eval` built-in for non-python commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having not come across any built-in capability to do this, I wrote the following function which accomplishes the broad intent.  Environment variable modifications and change of working directory are reflected in the python shell after the function returns.  Any modification of shell aliases or functions are *not* retained but that could be done too with enhancement of this function.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

"""
Some functionality useful when working with IPython as a shell replacement.
"""


import subprocess
import tempfile
import os

def ShellEval(command_str):
    """
    Evaluate the supplied command string in the system shell.
    Operates like the shell eval command:
       -  Environment variable changes are pulled into the Python environment
       -  Changes in working directory remain in effect
    """
    temp_stdout = tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile()
    temp_stderr = tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile()
    # in broader use this string insertion into the shell command should be given more security consideration
    subprocess.call("""trap 'printf "\\0`pwd`\\0" 1>&2; env -0 1>&2' exit; %s"""%(command_str,), stdout=temp_stdout, stderr=temp_stderr, shell=True)
    temp_stdout.seek(0)
    temp_stderr.seek(0)
    all_err_output = temp_stderr.read()
    allByteStrings = all_err_output.split(b'\x00')
    command_error_output = allByteStrings[0]
    new_working_dir_str  = allByteStrings[1].decode('utf-8') # some risk in assuming index 1. What if commands sent a null char to the output?

    variables_to_ignore = ['SHLVL','COLUMNS', 'LINES','OPENSSL_NO_DEFAULT_ZLIB', '_']

    newdict = dict([ tuple(bs.decode('utf-8').split('=',1)) for bs in allByteStrings[2:-1]])
    for (varname,varvalue) in newdict.items():
        if varname not in variables_to_ignore:
            if varname not in os.environ:
                #print("New Variable: %s=%s"%(varname,varvalue))
                os.environ[varname] = varvalue
            elif os.environ[varname] != varvalue:
                #print("Updated Variable: %s=%s"%(varname,varvalue))
                os.environ[varname] = varvalue
    deletedVars = []
    for oldvarname in os.environ.keys():
        if oldvarname not in newdict.keys():
            deletedVars.append(oldvarname)
    for oldvarname in deletedVars:
        #print("Deleted environment Variable: %s"%(oldvarname,))
        del os.environ[oldvarname]

    if os.getcwd() != os.path.normpath(new_working_dir_str):
        #print("Working directory changed to %s"%(os.path.normpath(new_working_dir_str),))
        os.chdir(new_working_dir_str)
    # Display output of user's command_str.  Standard output and error streams are not interleaved.
    print(temp_stdout.read().decode('utf-8'))
    print(command_error_output.decode('utf-8'))
```